# How do I - Incrementally deploy in debug mode and other wise using Eclipse Helios and JBoss Tools

Tags: eclipse, jboss

Environment

Win7

Eclipse Helios, Eclipse 3.6.1

Java 6

Jboss Tools version 1.0.0.v20110123-0129-H10-CR1 from the nightly builds

Jboss 4.2.3

In the past I used MyEclipse, which is a paid tool. In myEclipse, it's easy to configure a JBOSS Server and then deploy 
 your webproject in it.  While in debug mode, if I change a java class (OR JSP), its changes are immediately reflected under Jboss and
 I can test that change, without doing any explicit redeployment
 So myeclipse had these features working outof the box....

I'm trying to accomplish same functionality with Eclipse Helios and Jboss Tools

Case 1

- I added the Jboss Server via Java EE perspective->Add Server etc...
- And then added my WebProject to this Jboss Server
- When I right click on this added project and publish from here, it runs an ant script, to create a single (Standard) war file...and it always does the whole thing over.
  I dont get a choice to deploy it expanded and anything to specify an incremental deployment

Case 2

- Since Case 1 didnt allow exploded war and anything incremental, I decided to use JBOSS Tools
- So I opened, Window->Show View->Other->Jboss Tools->Project archives
- Selected my webproject, after which it showed up in the "Project archives" tab
- So then....Right click on the project name in "project archives" tab.....->New Archive->WAR...and I added my project to deploy in exploded form. ok.
- Now if I right click on the added WAR and click "Build Archive (full)"....it deploys the whole web project.  Everytime it does the whole thing, instead of incremental.
- Since that option didnt do it incrementally, so I right clicked and clicked "Publish to Server".  The window that pops up, doesnt show me any servers...from where do i add to this?

  In summary....

  A) I havent seen any way to incrementally deploy

  B) When I'm in debug mode, my java file changes dont reflect immediately...I dont mind redeploying, but since its not incremental, its annoying to do the whole thing over and over.

  So question is ...

  1) How do I do an incremental deployment?

  2) How do I configure this, such that my changes in java classes are reflected immediately when in debug mode.

  btw I have seen people suggest an alternate soln to use a custom ANT script....But will ANT script incrementally deploy, if I use it's copy command?

  Thanks
  Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's MUCH simpler than this.

Forget about JBoss tools Archives, simply use the WTP adapter that JBoss tools provides. This one does incremental deployment (like MyEclipse).

Make sure you install `JBossAS Tools` from JBoss tools (yes the name sucks). Its description is:

> Provides a WTP adapter for JBoss AS 4.x and 5.x. Supports incremental and exploded deployment.

Dish the WTP Server adaptor you created earlier from "Add Server etc..." and do it again, but this time don't choose from "JBoss" but choose from the new folder "JBoss Community". You'll see several new adapters there with the red logo and a slightly different name (e.g. WTP bundled is `JBoss v5.0` but the one supplied by JBossAS Tools is `JBoss AS 5.0`).

Alternatively you can also use JRebel, which does incremental deployment no matter what WTP adapter you use (you disable the automatic deployment in that case).